# How to get from Mirpur New City to Benazir Bhutto Airport?

Tags: airport-transfer, pakistan, isb

What's the fastest way to get from Mirpur New City to Benazir Bhutto Airport? I tried looking for private car hire or shuttles but can't find anything reliable.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Mirpur/Islamabad-Airport-ISB), the only way is by vehicle, private or hired. Even the [Islamabad International Airport guide to access](http://www.islamabadairport.com.pk/) mentions only taxis, but offers no lists or links to companies.

A Google search for Mirpir taxi returns a number with Facebook pages, in English:

[Airport Express](https://www.facebook.com/buttcabing/)

[New Prince Travels](https://www.facebook.com/princetravel007/)

[Haider Cabs Mirpur](https://www.facebook.com/haidercabsinmirpur/)

[Ace Taxis Mirpur](https://www.facebook.com/ACETAXISMIRPUR/)